# Redirect local traffic to proxy port with iptables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, proxy

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 host that has a squid proxy on it running on port 8080. I want to proxy all the web traffic from the host through squid using iptables. Is the correct method:

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

This is not working. When I browse to a page it appears normally, even when the proxy is disabled. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Try this.
This is what you are exactly looking for if am right.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182421/forwarding-a-localhostport-to-an-externalipnewport/183359#183359

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr** Your command is very close. You need to remove the `-d 127.0.0.1` fragment and ensure you run your proxy process as a different user and exclude that user from the filter with `-m owner ! --uid-owner <other-username>` so the proxy doesn't have its traffic redirected to itself.

**More detail**

I found that most of the suggestions for configuring `iptables` for transparent
proxy make the assumption that the proxy machine is on a *separate* host from the
clients. I want to proxy traffic that originates *from* my machine (and I also
run the proxy on the same machine).

The way I read your questions makes me think you want the same thing.

This [blog post](https://www.darkcoding.net/software/decrypt-your-https-traffic-with-mitmproxy/) mentions the fix:

> **localhost too**
>
> If you want to run the client on the same machine as the server
>   (you’re in a coffee shop on your laptop; have a pastry for me), we
>   can’t use the PREROUTING table, because it only applies to packets
>   coming from outside. What we can do is modify the destination port on
>   packets  *OUTPUT*  by our client process. The catch is that it will
>   also affect packets output by mitmproxy, and we’ll get into a routing
>   loop.
>
> There are probably several ways to solve this, but the one that worked
>   for me was running mitmproxy as root, and making the iptables rule 
>   *not*  apply to root-owned processes.
>
> ```
> sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner root --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
> ```
>
> - **-m owner**: Load the  *owner*  module.
> - **! –uid-owner root**: Rule does not apply to root-owned processes
>
> Remember that in this case you’ll run mitmproxy as root. This will
>   also log all your https web browser traffic. Add  `-m multiport`  and
>   replace  `--dport`  with  `--dports`  to intercept multiple ports (or
>   just repeat the line with a different port).

And this [mitmproxy forum thread](https://discourse.mitmproxy.org/t/transparent-proxying-on-a-single-machine-iptables/97) has a solution so you don't have to run as root. You create a separate user specifically to run mitmproxy and then exclude that user's uid in the iptables filter.

I found that the thread linked in the comment by @keerthi isn't quite right because that is about forwarding a single port on localhost, whereas I think you want to forward *all* traffic.

Comment: after about 8 hours of trying to figure out why it doesn't work I finally came across your answer - I understand why it wasn't working before now as well

Answer (score 4):

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`

In your rule, IPTables will **only** redirect traffic **destined for localhost** to the proxy. This rule will redirect **any** traffic destined for port 80. In your rule, change **-d** to **-s** and it shall work.

Comment: You can change that `-A` to `-I` to see immediate effect on the command line.

Comment: I think the --dport is routing incoming traffic.

Comment: @MichaelCole Yes. Incoming into the [NAT table](http://rlworkman.net/howtos/iptables/iptables-tutorial.html#TRAVERSINGOFTABLES), from anywhere, including localhost.