# iptables forward all traffic through proxy

Tags: networking, iptables, proxy, nat, tcp

I need to redirect all tcp traffic coming out of local programs to the interface that is able to connect to a proxy server.

According to this picture

[image]

I need to add rules to the `OUTPUT` chain, but almost everywhere said that I need to add rules like this

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Could someone explain why ? As far as I can understand this rule is applied for all incoming traffic but not outgoing traffic ?

I have tried something like that

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --jump DNAT --to-destination 192.168.56.1:8080
```

But this doesn't work 
It shows me that HTTP request is invalid.

Could someone please explain how to forward all traffic through proxy and explain why a specific table/chain is used ?

Comment: I answered a similar question here https://serverfault.com/a/977515/265053 but that one has the proxy running on the same host. You might find some help to get started there though.