# route tcp traffic through tor and udp traffic through vpn using iptables

Tags: iptables, vpn, tor

I'm trying to route all tcp traffic to go through tor (localhost:9050) and all udp traffic to go through an openvpn vpn. I've got an idea on how to do it, but I think I might be way off base. Could someone show and explain how to write these rules?

Update: I tried to use the rule listed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/848775/iptables-forward-all-traffic-through-proxy):

I slightly modified it to: sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 9050

ip r outputs:

default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0  proto static 
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 1

Comment: You should write what you idea is. And what you have already tried. You should include the commands you used in your question as well as the output of `ip r`.

Comment: @ender.qa I edited my comment, hope that helps! I don't know what you mean by my idea, I think I explained it clearly. Let me know what you want to be clarified further please

Comment: What's listening on port 9050?

Comment: @IporSircer [tor proxy](https://www.torproject.org/)

Comment: Wouldn't this more related guide also be worth checking? [tor wiki TransparentProxy](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy)