# Redirect all local traffic to shadow-socks proxy

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, proxy, socks

### Iptables reroute to shadowsocks

I have ubuntu 20.04 vps with shadow-socks server on it.

I also have ubuntu 20.04 on my pc, with shadow-socks client running on it.
Currently using [shadow-socks-libev](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev) version.

---

**The goal is to redirect all requests to 127.0.0.1:1080, where proxy client is running.**

I followed recommendations from [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/490594/redirect-local-traffic-to-proxy-port-with-iptables) question and [this](https://www.darkcoding.net/software/decrypt-your-https-traffic-with-mitmproxy/) blog, where the answer is pointing to.
Also saw [this](https://discourse.mitmproxy.org/t/transparent-proxying-on-a-single-machine-iptables/97) qna.

However, nothing made it work for me.

---

### Steps I made

I. I created admin user for running shadow socks client only.

II. I made systemd unit to start client on boot from separate user, content of file listed below:

```
[Unit]
Description=SahdowSocks
After=network.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=ss-local -c /etc/shadowsocks-client/config.json
Restart=on-failure
User=socks_user
Group=socks_user

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

At this point if I'm setting 127.0.0.1:1080 in my browser (firefox) as a socks5 proxy - it works fine.

III. Then I made iptables rules, according to the links above.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner socks_user --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1080
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner socks_user --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1080
```

After that, I can still use the browser if connected directly to the proxy through settings, but after switching to no proxy/system proxy - getting request timeout. All other apps also have no connection.

*Just to mention, if I do ping to 1.1.1.1 it returns fine

*If I do wget http://someurl it ends with no result.

So I assume I'm getting reroute loop (?), but don't understand why.

Comment: Answer could be found here: 

https://superuser.com/questions/1670641/redirect-all-local-traffic-to-shadow-socks-proxy